Maatwebsite Rules Validation Failed on Import Data from Excel File on Laravel 10
Recently, I have been working on the project that needs to enable users to import data using the excel template file. I provided the excel file which contains the header like as the followings :

name_title_code -> The code of name title Ex. 003 for Ms.
fname -> First Name
lname -> Last Name
gender -> Gender when you were born
citizen_id -> The Citizen ID on the ID Card
registered_address -> The place you were born
mailing_address -> The current address that can use to contact you
is_same_address -> Ask whether the mailing address is the same as registered address
is_current_outside_country -> Ask whether currently live in the country or others

The type of value will be as shown :

name_title_code -> 3 digits number with leading zero(s)
fname -> string/text
lname -> string/text
gender -> F for Female and M for Male
citizen_id -> 13 digits number
registered_address -> string/text
mailing_address -> string/text
is_same_address -> boolean either 1 for true or 0 for false
is_current_outside_country -> boolean either 1 for true or 0 for false

I'm using Maatwebsite. I had created model for importing data from Excel with this command line : 'php artisan make:import ImportUser' and get 'ImportUser' under 'App\Imports\ImportUser' in Laravel Folder. The followings are my code in the ImportUser.
     <?php 

     namespace App\Imports;
     use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

     use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
     use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
     use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithStartRow;
     use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
     use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;
     use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsEmptyRows;

     use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
     use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;

     use Auth;
     use App\Models\User;
     
     class ImportUser implements ToModel, WithStartRow, WithHeadingRow, WithValidation, SkipsEmptyRows, ToCollection
     {
         use Importable;

         public function model(array $row)
         {
              // Define Each Row
              return new User([
                   'name_title_code' => $row['name_title_code'],
                   'lname' => $row['lname'],
                   'gender' => $row['gender'],
                   'citizen_id' => $row['citizen_id'],
                   'registered_address' => $row['registered_address'],
                   'mailing_address' => $row['mailing_address'],
                   'is_same_address' => $row['is_same_address'],
                   'is_current_outside_country' => $row['is_current_outside_country'],
                   'created_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
                   'created_by' => Auth::user()->id,
                   'updated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
                   'updated_by' => Auth::user()->id,
              ]);
         }

         public function startRow():int
         {
              // Skip The First Row as Header
              return 2;
         }

         public function rules(): array
         {
               return [
                    'name_title_code' => ['required', Rule::exists('name_title', 'code')],
                    'fname' => 'required',
                    'lname' => 'required',
                    'gender' => ['required', Rule::in('F', 'M')],
                    'citizen_id' => ['required', 'digits:13', Rule::unique('users', 'citizen_id')],
                    'registered_address' => 'required',
                    'mailing_address' => [Rule::requiredIf('is_same_address', 0)],
                    'is_same_address' => ['required', 'boolean'],
                    'is_current_outside_country' => ['required', 'boolean', Rule::declinedIf('is_same_address', 1)],

                    '*.name_title_code' => ['required', Rule::exists('name_title', 'code')],
                    '*.fname' => 'required',
                    '*.lname' => 'required',
                    '*.gender' => ['required', Rule::in('F', 'M')],
                    '*.citizen_id' => ['required', digits:13, Rule::unique('users', 'citizen_id')],
                    '*.registered_address' => 'required',
                    '*.mailing_address' => [Rule::requiredIf('is_same_address', 0)],
                    '*.is_same_address' => ['required', 'boolean'],
                    '*.is_current_outside_country' => ['required', 'boolean', Rule::declinedIf('is_same_address', 1)],
               ];
         }
     }

The followings are some part of the code in my ExcelController for import function :
public function import(Request $request)
{
    // For Basic Validation
    // Conditions for Basic Validation
    $rules = [
        'file' => 'required|mimes:xlsx,xls',
    ];
    
    // Messages for Basic Errors
    $messages = [
        'file.required' => 'Please choose the file you want.',
        'file.mimes' => 'The file must be with the extension of .xlsx or .xls only.',
    ];

    // Validate Data
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);

    // Error Case : Return Error
    if ($validator->fails()) {

        return redirect()
                    ->back()
                    ->withInput()
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->with('error', 'Sorry!\nSomething went wrong!');
    }

    // Success Case  
    else {
        
        // Advanced Validation(s)
        // NO

        // Get File
        $file = $request->file('file');

        try{

            // Process The Excel File
            Excel::import(new ImportUser, $file);

            return  redirect()
                    ->back()
                    ->with('success', 'Successfully Add Data from Excel!');
        } 
        catch(\Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\ValidationException $e){

            $failures = $e->failures();

            return  redirect()
                    ->back()
                    ->with('error', 'Something went wrong in your file!')
                    ->with('failures', $failures);
        }
    }
}

I cannot use the specified rules in the 'ImportUser' to validate the value of each cell in each row such as Rule::unique('table_name', 'column_name), Rule::requiredIf('field_name', some_value) and Rule::declinedIf('field_name', some_value). For example, I migrated the database so all the records are gone and tried to insert data with Excel but it keeps telling that the 'citizen_id' is not unique while there is no records in the database at all.
It keep failing when I try to insert data and keep telling that there is something wrong with the rules I declared. I don't know why. If anyone has any ideas about this, please do not hesitate to leave yours here.
For more information, I'm using Maatwebsite version 3.1 and my PHP version is 8.2 if you think this is the cause of the problem. However, I have checked that Maatwebsite version 3.1 is supported for PHP version 8.0 and later. What do you think about this? Please tell me your opinion.
Thank you in advanced.
